# Display total price for each row where quantity comes from database and price is entered by user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-5

I have a table in my Blazor Asp.Net 5 application with 4 columns:

1. Title
2. Quantity
3. Price
4. Total

Each time a user enters a price in column 3, I want the column 4 cell to be updated live by 3x2 (quantity X price) for the row in which he types it. How can I achieve this?

There may be many rows and data arrives from database.

Data is displayed to user and allows him to enter prices for each product row, meanwhile quantity is already populated:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < advert.Products.Count; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    var item = advert.Products[i];
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">@index</th>
    <td>@item.Title</td>
    <td>@item.Qty</td>
    <td><input /></td>
    <td>Sum here</td>
    </tr>
}
@code {
    [Parameter] public int AdvertId { get; set; }
    public Advert advert;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        advert = await adRepo.GetAdvert(AdvertId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

Model:

```
public class Advert
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Index.razor:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < advert.Products.Count; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    var item = advert.Products[i];
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">@index</th>
        <td>@item.Title</td>
        <td>@item.Qty</td>
        <td><input @bind="@item.Price" /></td>
        <td>@{
            var total = item.Price * item.Qty;
        }
        @total</td>
    </tr>
}
@code {
    [Parameter] public int AdvertId { get; set; }
    public Advert advert;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        advert = await adRepo.GetAdvert(AdvertId);

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]